# Copy file system hierarchy partially from one drive to another and make tar package in simple way (in C /Linux)

Tags: c, linux, shell

Basically I want to do upgrade the filesystem of the current filesystem present in the linux based microcontroller. But problem is I don't want to upgrade it fully but most of the files .  File system has tree like structure with different bin,conf,config,lib,opt,firmware folders  files (like **[filesystem](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/913e18a5cd8258f4f0fa8bdece7c228520210201180944/f7b9c6)**).Also .ko files,kernel files will be there . I want to copy selective things from the **filesystem**.Say I have hard disk connected to it with path as /mnt/sata and one created folder as **upgrade**.

So I want to copy the above filesystem package into this **upgrade** folder to use it for further use.
So what will be easy solution for it? Is it possible to do it using C program with Linux system commands/shell scripting?

Comment: It’s unclear why you want to do this in C at all. You could just run e.g. `tar cfj /mnt/sata/backup.tar.bz2 /bin /conf … etc.` to back up what you need.

Comment: Please don't ask "is it possible" questions. Just about anything is possible if you have enough time and money. Instead please **show us code that illustrates the problem you're trying to solve**.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph ok fine. I thought of using c program. But how to copy files **selectively**( not all) from different folders of the file system and take backup??

Comment: What's wrong with using Linux-standard software delivery packages like RPMs to do this?  That's what they're designed to do.  Do you really think your first-time efforts to replicate that functionality will work as well as well-tested utilities that are several decades old?

Comment: @user3559780 That entirely depends on *how* you want to select these files. `tar` just takes a list of arguments and processes those indiscriminately. If you want to *select* files, you need to do that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you can execute commands in C in two ways :

- using system("your command")
- using pipeopen("your command" , "read or write or both")

what did system() do ? it just executes the command given

what did pipeopen do ? it redirects the output of your command

that mean if your goal is to just executing a command use system and if your need is to execute the command and handle it's output use pipeopen

The command to copy file in linux is :

`cp filename /destinationfolder`

in your program to execute this command do :

`system("cp filename /destinationfolder")`